# PowerShell concatenation

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a simple line of code that will delete various user files from a C disk for various servers. How do I concatenate with PowerShell to get the pathway to a server?

For instance, this is what I'm trying to do, but PowerShell isn't recognizing the `+` symbol as concatenation I think:

```
remove-item "\\$server" + '\C$\Documents and Settings\a409126' -force -recurse -whatif
```

I get an error saying:

```
Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+'.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

`remove-item ("\\$server" + '\C$\Documents and Settings\a409126') -force -recurse -whatif`

You need to know more about [command mode vs. expression mode](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/effective-powershell-item-10-understanding-powershell-parsing-modes/) to be effective in PoSH

Comment: It works! Thanks so much! So just the simple parenthesis were causing the issue? Strange, but nice to know for the future.

Comment: there are two modes in PoSH you need to know about. see link in original answer.

Comment: Hmm now it makes sense why the code that I had written above was working fine with other parts of my code where I was assigning that to a variable rather than doing what I was trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use variable expansion:

```
Remove-Item "\\$server\C$\Documents and Settings\a409126" -Force ...
```

Another way is with the `Join-Path` cmdlet:

```
Join-Path -Path \\$server -ChildPath 'C$\Documents and Settings\a409126'
```

Comment: c$ is going to cause a problem in your first example unless you use single quotes ;)

Comment: Apparently it doesn't. With double quotes '$' is not expanded since there are no characters after it.

Answer (score 0):

You want remove items from path which you should join, so:

```
Join-Path "\\$server" "C$\Documents and Settings\a409126" |Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Whatif
```